# How to make a filter system in search view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a recyclerview that is filtered by a search view in the top toolbar.
This recyclerview is in a vertical grid as you can see. It contains these cards that have several data such as title, a date and more.
I need to make a filter system, so if I write something starting with the character "&":
[image: img1]

the app recognizes that you're filtering by date,  instead of searching by title.

[image: img2]

It will search in this other text views, like date.

[image: img3]

How could I do that?

**Update**
This is my current code, it's not working.

```
  //Adapter Code
     public class TaskAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder> 
    implements Filterable
    {


    private ArrayList<TaskItem> mTaskList;
    private List<TaskItem> fulltasklist;
    public HashMap<Integer, TaskViewHolder> TaskHolders 
    = new HashMap<>();

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<TaskItem> exampleList)
    {

        mTaskList = exampleList;
        fulltasklist = new ArrayList<>(exampleList);
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return TaskFilter;
    }

    public void setFilter(List<TaskItem> filteredList)
    {
        mTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
        mTaskList.addAll(filteredList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private Filter TaskFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence 
        constraint) {
            List<TaskItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

           /* if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)
            {
                filteredList.addAll(fulltasklist);

            }
            else
            {
                String FilterPattern = 
          constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (TaskItem item : fulltasklist)
                {
                    if 
       (item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(FilterPattern))
                    {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }*/

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence 
      constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mTaskList.clear();
            mTaskList.addAll((List)results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

    //Main Fragment (The one with the recyclerview and 
    toolbar)     

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater 
    inflated, @Nullable View Group container, @Nullable 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true) ;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homefragment, 
     container, false);
     mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.HomeRecycler);
        madap = new TaskAdapter(TaskList);                
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(G);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);







  mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_C 
    ACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(madap);
    } 

     @Override
      public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, 
     MenuInflater inflater)
    {

        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_toolbaritems, menu);


        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
       item.getActionView();
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
      SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
        {
                newText = newText.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<TaskItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<> 
      ( );

                if (newText.length() == 0 || (newText.length() == 1 
        && newText.equalsIgnoreCase("&")))
                {
                    filteredList.addAll(TaskList);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(TaskItem item : TaskList)
                    {
                        if (newText.charAt(0) == '&')
                        {
                            String date = item.getDate().toLowerCase();
                            if (date.contains(newText))
                            {
                                filteredList.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String title = item.getTitle().toLowerCase();
                            if (title.contains(newText))
                            {
                                filteredList.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                madap.setFilter(filteredList);
                return true;
            }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in your adapter class**

```
//replace YourDataModelClass with the class that contains title, date, time etc. as property
public void setFilter(List<YourDataModelClass> filteredList){
    adapterDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterDataList.addAll(filteredList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**In your activity class modify your searchView's onQueryTextListener in that way, and you'll get your desired result**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String queryText) {

            //Match search query ignoring upper/lower case
            queryText = queryText.toLowerCase();

            //replace YourDataModelClass with the class that contains title, date, time etc. as property
            List<YourDataModelClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(queryText.length() == 0 || (queryText.length() == 1 && queryText.equalsIgnoreCase("&"))) {
                filteredList.addAll(actualList);
            } else {
                for (YourDataModelClass yourDataModelObject: actualList){

                    if(queryText.charAt(0) == '&') {

                        String date = yourDataModelObject.getDate().toLowerCase();
                        if (date.contains(queryText)) {
                            filteredList.add(yourDataModelObject);
                        }

                    } else {

                        String title = yourDataModelObject.getTitle().toLowerCase();
                        if (title.contains(queryText)) {
                            filteredList.add(yourDataModelObject);
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
                mAdapter.setFilter(filteredList);
                return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: In the second code, what is actual list? For some reason it isn't working

Comment: actualList is the same kind of list as filteredList..in your code there's somewhere you've written List<YourDataModelClass> actualList = new ArrayList<>();  and then you fetched your data and inserted it inside actualList

Comment: I updated the question with my code because I think I have a typo error or something like that @ash12